# how to add comment or label to the graph in RDFLib?

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

I'm trying to add names of datasets to the graph object and later retrieve them, pretty sure there must be easy way to accomplish it, but could not find anything so far ... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is to attach a context to a graph. It's like creating a graph out parsing subgraphs in it, each subgraph with a name - a `URIRef` in case of rdflib.

Imagine you have to graphs represented by the two following files:

dataA.nt

```
<http://data.org/inst1> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> "david" .
<http://data.org/inst2> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> "luis" .
<http://data.org/inst3> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> "max" .
```

dataB.nt

```
<http://data.org/inst1> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows> <http://data.org/inst2> .
<http://data.org/inst2> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows> <http://data.org/inst3> .
<http://data.org/inst3> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows> <http://data.org/inst1> .
```

And the following piece of code :

```
import rdflib

g = rdflib.ConjunctiveGraph("IOMemory",)

#g is made of two sub-graphs or triples gathered in two different contexts.
#the second paramaters identifies the URIRef for each subgraph.
g.parse("dataA.nt",rdflib.URIRef("http://mygraphs.org/names"),format="n3")
g.parse("dataB.nt",rdflib.URIRef("http://mygraphs.org/relations"),format="n3")

print "traverse all contexts and all triples for each context"
for subgraph in g.contexts():
    print "Graph name",subgraph.identifier 
    for triple in subgraph.triples((None,None,None)):
        print triple

print "traverse all contexts where a triple appears"
for subgraph in g.contexts(triple=(rdflib.URIRef('http://data.org/inst1'),rdflib.URIRef("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name"),rdflib.Literal(u'david'))):
    print "Graph name",subgraph.identifier 
    for triple in subgraph.triples((None,None,None)):
        print triple

print "traverse a triple pattern regardless the context is in"
for t in g.triples((None,rdflib.URIRef("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name"),None)):
    print t
```